# validate a single field in a form of multiple field using vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js

I have an emailValidation method that I want to run if `this.$refs.editUserForm.validate('email')` is true but if I enter the email as `jack@xyz.com` or any valid email it always returns `this.$refs.editUserForm.validate('email')` as false. Help me find out how can I check the validation of a single field in a form.

```
<template>
  <v-form ref="editUserForm" :model="user" data-app>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="user.first_name"
      label="First Name"
      :rules="firstNameRules"
      class="required"
      required
    >
    </v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="user.email"
      label="Email"
      :rules="emailRules"
      name="email"
      class="required"
      required
      @blur="emailValidation"
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      client: {
        first_name: '',
        email: ''
      },
      firstNameRules: [
        value => !!value || 'Please enter a first name'
      ],
      emailRules: [ 
        v => /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail must 
        be valid'
      ]
    };
  },


  methods: {
    emailValidation(){
      if (this.$refs.editUserForm.validate('email')) {
        console.log("Valid")
      }
      else {
        console.log("Not Valid")
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the form's `validate` function does not take a string.  It will always validate the whole form and return the result, so even if the email field is valid it can still return false if other fields are invalid.

To validate just the one field, you need to give that field a `ref` and call `validate()` on just that one field's ref.

```html
<v-text-field
  ref="email"
  v-model="user.email"
  label="Email"
  :rules="emailRules"
  name="email"
  class="required"
  required
  @blur="emailValidation"
>
</v-text-field>
```

The validate code also depends on your version of Vuetify:

### Vuetify 2.x

```
emailValidation() {
  const valid = this.$refs.email.validate();
  if (valid) {
    console.log('Valid');
  } else {
    console.log('Not Valid');
  }
}
```

### Vuetify 3.x

`validate()` returns a promise so must use async/await

```js
async emailValidation() {
  const valid = await this.$refs.email.validate();
  // valid is as an array of possible error messages. A length of 0 indicates valid input
  if (valid.length === 0) {
    console.log('Valid');
  } else {
    console.log('Not Valid');
  }
}
```